# Unicode in Resources file is not getting recognized

Tags: c#

I have the following string in the Resources file.

`cm\x00B3` to show cm<sup>3</sup> in output. But the output shows `cm\x00B3` with unicode without applying superscript. Please help me how to show cm<sup>3</sup>

Comment: What is the code where you use this?

Comment: Escape sequences in string literals are translated by the C# compiler.  But resource files are not compiled by the C# compiler, so what you got is entirely normal.  Simplest workaround is to just copy/paste ³ when you edit the string in the resource editor.